# VPN connection when the Android app is starting

Tags: java, android, vpn

I'm developing a android app in Java. I need force a VPN connection when the app is starting. Is this  possible?

Thanks you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VpnService` in this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html)

or can set VPN on your network in **Setting** > **Networks** > **VPN**